# Pandas enlargement of multidimensional objects

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I want to add row to a multidimensional pd.Series.

```
b = pd.Series([1,1,2,3], index = [["digit", "digit", "digit", "digit"], ["one", "one", "two", "three"]])

b
Out[30]: 
digit  one      1
       one      1
       two      2
       three    3
dtype: int64
```

Now, when I do

```
b.loc["digit"].loc["four"] = 4
```

Nothing happens. There are no errors, but b remains the same.
Though this approach works with single-dimensional Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) because:

> PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.

and then tuple with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
b = b.sort_index()
b.loc[("digit", "four")] = 4
print (b)
digit  one      1
       one      1
       three    3
       two      2
       four     4
dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
c = pd.Series([4], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['digit'],['four']]))
b = pd.concat([b, c])
print (b)
digit  one      1
       one      1
       two      2
       three    3
       four     4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It even worked even without tupling indexes

Comment: hmm... the problem is, that when these approaches are working with Serieses. But in case of dataframes, I get additional column instead of row

Comment: Yes, then is necessary tuple.  `df.loc[("digit", "four"),:] = 4` for all columns. `df.loc[("digit", "four"),'col'] = 4` for add one value to cil.